# D3js Drag state is not changing when I scale svg programatically

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, vuejs2

The drag state does not change when the location of svg is programmatically.

I have created tree using and added zoom functionality to it using code below. Here’s the code:

```
d3.select('.hierarchy-container').append('svg')
     this.svg_zoom=d3.zoom()
     .scaleExtent([0.5,2])
     .on("zoom", (event)  =>{
         d3.select("#svg_group").attr("transform",event.transform)
       })
     this.svg=d3.select("svg")
     .attr('width','100%')
     .attr('height', '100%')
     .attr("viewBox", [-this.svg_container_dimension.width/2+120,-200, this.svg_container_dimension.width, this.svg_container_dimension.height])
     .style("user-select", "none")
     .call(this.svg_zoom)
     .append('g').attr('id',"svg_group")
```

When dragging and scrolling from the initial state, it works fine.
But, when I try to scale the svg through code, the drag state doesn’t change it’s coordinates. For example, if I scale the svg and it comes to left top where it was previously at bottom right. The drag state remains at bottom right.

Here’s the code of changing the scale:

```
    this.svg.transition().duration(750).call(this.svg_zoom.scaleTo,0.6)
```

The tree get scale to 0.6 but when i start draging after scaling it programatically it goes back to previous state of x, y and scale.

I am using D3 version 7.8.5

Here is what I am talking about
[Problem Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feITC.gif)

Things I had tried are
-> insead of d3 zoom callback function i selected svg and translate it to new position.
-> Refered this https://www.d3indepth.com/zoom-and-pan/
-> Tried shifting viewbox of svg instead of translating it.